# How to override themeroller background color?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How can I override the default background color for a thememrolled widget?

multiselect.css

```
.ui-multiselect { ...
    background-color:#fff;  /* trying to override to display white instead of themerolled blue */
 ...}
```

themeroller-custom.css

```
/* This is the line that I need to somehow override in my control .css */
/* I don't wont't to modify this because datepicker is using this with other widgets */
.ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default { border:   
1px solid #c5dbec; background: #dfeffc url(images/ui-bg_glass_85_dfeffc_1x400.png) 50% 50% repeat-x; 
font-weight: bold; color: #2e6e9e; }
```

Comment: Is editing the CSS itself not an option?

Comment: There are some very good reasons not to touch the CSS generated by the jQuery UI themeroller unless you do so through the themeroller interface which won't work if you just want to modify a single widget: When updating to a newer version of jQuery UI you usually take the themeroller link from the generated CSS file, open it, and press "download". Then you get the newest version with exactly the same theme as you had before - but of course any custom changes would be lost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This didn't work:

```
background-color:#fff !important
```

But this did (after verifying css rules where my style above was not crossed out via firebug)

```
background:#fff !important;
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the property *important*:

```
.ui-multiselect {
    background-color: #fff !important;
}
```

Otherwise the selector would have to be more specific than the original one or exactly as specific but loaded after the original one (by including that stylesheet later). However, neither ways are clear or easy so using `!important` is the best way (and also the most intuitive one for someone looking at the CSS - he seems immediately that you do want that rule instead of whatever was defined somewhere else)

Comment: Hi, couldn't get the !important; to stick.

Comment: You might want to use firebug to check the CSS rules that are active for the element.

Comment: I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: You are apparently a developer, so installing a browser extension and trying to figure out how it works (it's really easy!) should't be a problem for you...

Comment: You'll want to check if your rule is overridden by another rule (in that case your rule is striked out). If you post a link to your site I can have a look, too.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
.ui-multiselect {
   background-color:#fff !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to just set `background-color` on `ui-multiselect` there was a problem when dropdown is opened: header was just white and not showing any text. So my solution is:

```
.ui-multiselect:not(.ui-state-active) {
    background: #fff !important;
}
```

So background override will only apply when dropdown is not in active state. This will not work in older versions of IE.